# WFS from ArcGIS Online download failed or partially failed

Tags: qgis-3, arcgis-online, wfs

I've made a WFS service from a Feature Layer in ArcGIS Online. When connecting to the service in QGIS and adding the data to a project it works as expected. But after panning / inspecting the data I'm getting seemingly random log messages that I cannot pinpoint as they happen in different datasets of the WFS service (but same errors).

WFS log message:

> 2019-11-20T11:28:37     WARNING    Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: mismatched tag on line 1, column 907

Log Message:

> 2019-11-20T11:28:37     CRITICAL    Layer ProfielScout_Vast_punt : Download of features for layer MudManagerWFS:ProfielScout_Vast_punt failed or partially failed: Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: mismatched tag on line 1, column 907. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5

**What I tried:**

- Load WFS in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 - works fine
- Request in browser - works fine
- Navigate (in browser) to feature using `GetFeature`and `typeName` and check for *mismatched tag on line 1, column 907*. But no column 907 on line 1, see result.

Result:

```xml
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:MudManagerWFS="http://dservices9.arcgis.com/arcgis/services/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/MudManagerWFS/WFSServer" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" timeStamp="2019-11-20T10:43:31Z" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="29" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://dservices9.arcgis.com/arcgis/services/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/MudManagerWFS/WFSServer https://dservices9.arcgis.com/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/arcgis/services/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/MudManagerWFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=wfs%26version=2.0.0%26request=DescribeFeatureType">
```

Using **QGIS 3.8.3-Zanzibar**

Anyone have any idea where this error comes from?

Comment: Is the https://dservices9.arcgis.com/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/arcgis/services/5s3Rxz5DTD3G8MR4/MudManagerWFS/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typenames=your_typename a valid response?

Comment: Is the GetFeature response (that works in a browser) XML valid?

Comment: @nmtoken Your first link gives a valid response. I've checked the XML validity with the w3schools validator and it doesn't return any errors.